# ASP MVC one time login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Given the following scenario:
I have an email address. 
I want the owner of that email address to click on a link that I send to him by email. 
The page that I want the user to visit must be protected by a password, this password can be included in the mail that I send to him.

The site that the user is interacting with is using the simple membership provider for the regular users, but I don't want to use that system for this special one time visitor, as it leads to more tasks administering and cleaning up.

What are my alternatives?

Comment: Create a new role for the one time user, and check for the role on logout deleting the user in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the email to the user, generate a random password and save it in the table against the email address. You will also store some unique id that you will pass it to the link you provide in the email. This unique id in the url will be used to identify the email address and also the one time password (OTP). It is also better to have an expiry date for the password. So your database table will have the following columns.

```
Unique Link Id
Email address
One Time Password
Expiry Date
```

That's it. When the link is clicked, access the unique id, ask OTP to the user and validate.